# How to find all tags in a XML document?

Tags: java, xml

Currently I´m using this method to find a specified tag in a XML document:

```
public static String parseDocument(byte[] stream, String tagName, String resourceName) {

        String result = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            Node tag = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0);
            result = tag.getAttributes().getNamedItem(resourceName).getNodeValue();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }
```

But this returns only the first match. How can I implement a method that returns all found tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NodeList tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < tags.getLength() ; i++) {
    values.add(tags.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```